# Moodle saving data to database from ASSOC ARRAY not Data Object

Tags: php, database, crud, moodle

so, i have this associative array, the key is the data column and the value is the data itself, other frameworks like kohana uses ORM that automatically creates the private $data = aray() and passes that to the database... so if

```
$class->data = "value";
$class->save() // $class->update()
```

this is easy, in frameworks with ORM, but how about moodle? i tried using $DB->insert_record() but the stdClass is hard creating. how could i pass arrays to the database in moodle? please i need help... here's my class

```
<?php

/**
 * Course completion Extention- student self marked - plugin
 *
 * @package   completion
 * @copyright 2012 Ekomerce Ltd
 * @author    Gavin Sanden <gavin@ekomerce.co.uk>
 */



completion_ext::$DB = $DB;

class completion_ext{
    private $data = array();
    public static $DB;

 /**
 * DB Table
 * @var string $table
 */
public $table = 'completion_ext';

/**
 * Array of required table fields, must start with 'id'.
 * @var array $required_fields
 */




 public static function fetch_all($params) {}
function __construct($data = null){
    if($data != null && is_array($data)){
        $this->data = $data;
    }
}
public static function get_from_user($user_id){
    $variables =  self::$DB->get_records('completion_ext',array(
        'user_id'=>$user_id
    ));
    $completion_array  = array();
    foreach($variables as $variable){
        $com = new completion_ext($variable);
        $completion_array[] = $com;
    }
    return $completion_array;

}

public static function exists($user, $course){
    return self::$DB->record_exists('completion_ext', array(
        'user_id'=>$user,
        'course'=>$course

    ));
}
public static function id_exists($id){
        return self::$DB->record_exists('completion_ext', array(
        'id'=>$id
    ));
}
public static function get_from_course($course, $user_id){
    $variables = self::$DB->get_record('completion_ext',array(
        'user_id'=>$user_id,
        'course'=>$course
    ));
    return new completion_ext($variables);
}
public function __set($dt, $vl){
    $this->data[$dt] = $vl;
}
public static function get_by_id($id){
    $variables = self::$DB->get_record('completion_ext',array(
        'id'=>$id
    ));
    return new completion_ext($variables);
}
public static function check_completion_from_user($user_id){
    self::$DB->record_exists($table, array(
        'user_id'=>$user_id
    ));
}
public function __get($dt){
    return $this->data[$dt];
}
public function save(){
    echo print_r($this->data);
}
public function update(){
    self::$DB->update_record("completion_ext", $this);
}
```

}
?>

Answer (score 0):

If you just need an stdClass object, it is simple:

```
$myObject = (object) array('propertyName' => 'value');
```

The casting operator `(object)` creates an stdClass instance with all the array indices as properties.

Comment: still wont work i chaned the code to this 'public function save(){
  return self::$DB->insert_record('completion_ext',(Object) $this->data);
  
 }'

Comment: Then something else is wrong. Don't you get some sort of error message?

Comment: i fixed the $CFG so all errors are returning. i linked it through ajax, alert(html) still wont work gives blank message, tried to echo $DB->insert_record() itself, but it sends me a 404,